# Selecting new option in HTML select tag after user adds the option?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

Currently I have a form that asks the user a series of questions, they answers those questions via a select tag object. Those options in the select tag are populated by a database via php and mySQL. If the user does not see an option that best fits the their answer, they are allowed to add in their own answer. They are then brought to a new page to register their new answer to the question. That form posts to a php script that then updates the data base and they are back to the original form with the questions with the newly added option now in the select tag. How would I go about making the newly added answer selected in the select tag after they are redirected? I have researched this idea and cant seem to find a answer. So im looking to bounce some ideas around if someone has one.

Comment: Provide code/research that you have attempted prior to asking this question. Strongly refer to [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing the new answers to the same database that you are pulling the options from in the first place?

What I would recommend doing is getting the last inserted ID from the database and storing it in the users session, and then using that to automatically have the answer they just inserted selected by default.

Comment: yes the answers are being added and populated by the same database. I had though about doing this, however, im using php sessions to save user information and javascript cookies to save the selected index of the previous answered question so that after they add a new option the previous answer are not unset. so i believe if i do that that the javascipt function that auto loads the previous answers would override setting the index of the select tag via php

Comment: Why not give it a different name then and account for that in your javascript?

Comment: okay so ive been playing with it and i can overwrite the cookie that saves the answer in the page that the user adds the new answer. and obviously the cookie is saved from page to page, however the cookie is currently being save in the format of a select option and the user is entering text into a text box so it really doesnt work. So i tried just creating a new cookie that if its not null when the page loads that the max index of the select tag is set. Is there a function that allows use to set the tag to its max index?

Comment: Just get the length of child nodes and then set the selected index using that